# How to save video when recording is interrupted by sending the application to background on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am expermenting with video recording on Windows Phone 8. I want to handle the situation when user is putting my app to background, while it is recording a video. I would like to save the already recorded video before quitting.
I am handling this situation using the code from this example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243896.aspx

```
private async Task StopRecordingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Stopping recording...");

        _isRecording = false;
        await _mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine("Stopped recording!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception when stopping video recording: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am calling this method from the:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
```

But the video is not being saved. In the debug console I get only the first message: "Stopping recording...", but there is no "Stopped recording!" message logged. It seems like the resources are being destroyed before I can handle them.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is moved to the background you only have a short amount of time to run code.

Instead of having saving be triggered when you navigate from the page, instead look at the [`Application.Suspending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending) event which allows you to use a deferral to try and run your code for a bit longer so you can finish tidying up before your app loses it's resource allocation.

Something like:

```
async protected void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs args)
{
    SuspendingDeferral deferral = args.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    await StopRecordingAsync();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I will try it.